# How can I use a GIF image instead of a progress bar at html?

Tags: html

I have the following html code, but I wanna put a gif in place of the progess bar.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="waitDialog" >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Processing...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
             <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what stops you from using

```
<img src="path/to/image.gif"/>
```

instead of

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

---

Try this, for example:

```
<img src="http://bit.ly/1GIHgLh"/>
```

*That's not a random GIF!* It really shows that something's loading :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in several ways:

One way is to add the gif image as a background-image in your CSS file:

```
.progress .progress-striped active{
    background-image: url("path/to/image.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div id='progressBar' style='display:none;'>
   <img src='http://www.barchart.com/shared/images/progress_bar.gif'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use the hide and show by jQuery

for example:

```
$("#progressBar").css('display','block');

$("#progressBar").css('display','none');
```